# Gatsby.js - custom css module produce none-effect

Tags: javascript, css, module, gatsby

I'm a newbie in Gatsby.js. I'm trying to use the css module's way to override the default css of Gatsby.js. But my setting produce not a singe effect.

Here my index.js in layouts folder :

```
import customCSS from "./css/custom.css"
<Logo className={customCSS.logo} />
```

Here my custom.css :

```
.logo{ 
    top: 5%;
    left : 5%;
    width: 300em; 
  }
```

The compilation is a success but again, no effect on the display,  any hint would be great,
Thanks

Comment: your overwrite css should be after default css, Are you sure?

Comment: yeah it works great now, thanks

Comment: Welcome @Webman